# Cordova- taking picture

Tags: javascript, cordova

so I'm still pretty new to cordova and right now, I'm using it to make an app and I'm trying to take a picture and then save it. Right now, I can't take a picture. All I have is a button and in the corresponding javascript file, a function is called when the button is pressed. I started off by running 'cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera'. This is what I tried:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);

function onDeviceReady() {

    $('#picture').on('click',function() {
            takePicture();
    }

    function takePicture() {

        if (!navigator.camera) {
            alert("Camera API not supported", "Error");
            return;
        }

        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {
            alert("test");
        }, function(err) {
            alert("Inside err");
        }, cameraOption);

        /*navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imagePath) {
            alert("test");  
            document.getElementByID("photoImg").setAttribute("src", imagePath);
            alert("Got picture");
        }, function() {
            alert("Photo canceled");
        },  {
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinatonType.FILE_URI
        });*/


    }
}
```

I got the function from http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/ and I also tried the second from another place, but the camera doesn't come up in either one. Also, I inserted some alerts inside and none of them appear, so I'm a bit confused.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get the camera to show up?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are calling your code inside the document ready callback, so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#picture').on('click',function() {
        takePicture();
    }
});
```

You are not showing your camera options, here is some code that works for me.

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    // This will show the photo in an <img> element with id="photo"
    jQuery('#photo').attr('src', imageURI).show();
    // Do more stuff here
}

var folder = true; // set to false to take with camera, true to select from library
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 25, // 25%
     // takes a photo that will fit precisely within an iPhone 6 Plus screen
    targetWidth: 1080,
    targetHeight: 960,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: folder ? Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I updated my code above, but I have all of my code inside onDeviceReady(). Do I need to do anything with the cordova camera plugin besides adding it at the beginning? It seems like the 'navigator.camera.getPicture()' isn't working.

Comment: In order for me to help you, you will have to give me more information, like for example some console log statements that show what is going on or something because as I said, the above code works for me, if you sign up for my beta, you will see for yourself http://www.jol-app.com/prerelease.html#source=stackoverflow